# How can I deploy my APEX desktop application for access by users from the Internet?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

After creating an APEX desktop application, how can I deploy it in my web server computer, just like some homepages written using PHP?

I know APEX can export applications to .sql format and import them to another computer running APEX, but does it mean the web server need to run Oracle and/or APEX locally so that it can render the pages of the APEX application upon request?

And, is it possible to export APEX applications to other formats such as PHP?

I am using Oracle APEX 5.1.3.

Comment: You need a server running Oracle and APEX to run an APEX application, there is no option to "export to PHP".

Comment: And there's no such thing as an "APEX desktop application"

Comment: @Scott Here I am referring to the application created under APEX, using Create Application and then select Desktop as APEX Desktop application, as opposed to mobile app. Not 100% sure what the actual name is.

Comment: Ahh, that's a different context to this discussion, and I see how our (my) wires were crossed. Your pages are generated from the database, so it's nothing local to your computer. A "desktop application" is probably terminology that needs reassessing.